# Running ASP.NET MVC under Mono/Linux with xsp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linux, mono, xsp, fedora11

I am porting an existing ASP.NET MVC applicationto Mono. I am actually trying to make it run under Fedora Linux 11.

After a few tweaks, I have managed to make the solution compile in MonoDevelop.

While trying to execute it with xsp web server, I get the following output:

> Handling exception type ConfigurationErrorsException
>   Message is Error Initializing the configuration system
>   IsTerminating is set to True

I believe that the problem is in my web.config but I cannot find any more info on the exception. Is there a log somewhere that could contain any more information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woo hoo!

I have managed to make it work. As expected, the problem was in the web.config. To figure it out, I have had to test the same code in Windows with Visual Studio .NET.

Still no way to know what's wrong with a web.config under XSP but it's not blocking me anymore.

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the  node and see if  everything seems to working fine again..

maybe you can check over here for more details:  (http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux).

Comment: Which node are you talking about?